# Iterating through children from parent in Unity and changing their coordinates

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

[Parent-child tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4Pt2.png)

I want to be able to change the coordinates of all of the individual units in a floor and deactivate some of the cubes in the units. I want to be able to access these game objects from a script that's attached to floor without hardcoding them in as: "public GameObject unit1; public GameObject unit2; public GameObject cube1; etc etc" because there will be many of them. I want to be able to iterate through them and change their coordinates and deactivate some of them in void Start(), but everything I've tried thus far has failed.

I've tried this, but couldn't change the coordinates in the ingame objects by changing them in Transform[] units in C#. I've also tried loading the children in every other way that's possible and changing their coordinates and got the same result.

```
Transform[] units = new Transform[floorObject.transform.childCount];

for (int i = 0; i < floorObject.transform.childCount; i++)
{
    units[i]= floorObject.transform.GetChild(i);
}
```

Comment: really not enough info so as a suggestion, you need to probably use: `GameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>()` and iterate over that. <-- where GameObject is the GameObject your script is attached to.

Comment: Ok, but how do I actually change their coordinates while iterating through them to have the children move ingame?

Comment: same as you move any game object..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't understand your question well. As far as I understand you want to move your child objects but the code you have provide only access the childs. So here I try something else (not tested). Make sure that code is attached parent object.

```
public class FloorManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        // Loop through all children
        for (int i = 0; i < transform.childCount; i++)
        {
            Transform child = transform.GetChild(i);

            // Here you can change the child position
            child.position += new Vector3(1, 0, 0); 
            
        }
    }

}
```